# Reading PCAP file with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I have about 10GB pcap data with IPv6 traffic to analyze infos stored in IPv6 header and other extension header. To do this I decided to use Scapy framework. I tried ***rdpcap*** function , but for such big files it is not recommended. It tries to load all file into memory and get stuck in my case. 
I found in the Net that in such situation ***sniff*** is recommended, my code look like:

```
def main():
   sniff(offline='traffic.pcap', prn=my_method,store=0)


def my_method(packet):
   packet.show()
```

In function called ***my_method*** I receive each packet separately and I can parse them, but.... 
When I call ***show*** function with is in-build framework method I got sth like this:
[image: result]

When opened in wireshark I got properly looking packet:
[image: result2]

Could you tell me how to parse this packets in scapy to get proper results?

EDIT:
According to the discussion in comments I found a way to parse PCAP file with Python. In my opinion the easies way is to use pyshark framework:

```
import pyshark
pcap = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_path) ### for reading PCAP file
```

It is possible to easily iterate read file with for loop

```
for pkt in pcap:
    #do what you want
```

For parsing IPv6 header following methods may be useful:

```
pkt['ipv6'].tclass            #Traffic class field
pkt['ipv6'].tclass_dscp       #Traffic class DSCP field
pkt['ipv6'].tclass_ecn        #Traffic class ECN field
pkt['ipv6'].flow              #Flow label field
pkt['ipv6'].plen              #Payload length field
pkt['ipv6'].nxt               #Next header field
pkt['ipv6'].hlim              #Hop limit field
```

Comment: @coder I understand that wireshark shows packet in a different way and I'm okey with that. But look on src ip address and how it is parsed by scapy - as far as I know it's not okey, but maybe I'm not right.

Comment: oh, yes you are right - I missed the **ipv6** part.

Comment: I opened bug issue on scapy github page (https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/579). @coder you mentioned that using wireshark will be more efficient. My goal is to take every value of header and do some statistics job - is wireshark able to performe this type of activity?

Comment: As far as I know there are scripts and tools related to Wireshark that help do this kind of job, such as `capinfos` and `tshark` but I haven't used them much in the past. - but I think they can be used to do statistical analysis. You can find them here: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools

Comment: For example you could dump all `source ips` with the command: `tshark -T fields -e ip.src -r your_file.pcap`, or by changing `ip.src` to `ip.dst` you could parse dst ips (it is very similar to scapy). There also many other fields to try (like: frame.time, dns.qry.name, tcp.port and many other `wireshark fields`)

Comment: @coder Thanks a lot for your help. I will look carefully on tshark :)

Comment: I forgot also to mention that there is also a python tshark wrapper (**pyshark**) here: https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark

Comment: For example you could do: `import pyshark`,
`cap = pyshark.FileCapture('v6.pcap')`, and then
`for packet in cap: print packet.ipv6.src`

Answer (score 13):

**Update**

The latest [scapy](/questions/tagged/scapy) versions now **support** `ipv6` parsing.
So to parse an *ipv6 ".pcap" file* with [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) now it can be done like so:

```
from scapy.all import *

scapy_cap = rdpcap('file.pcap')
for packet in scapy_cap:
    print packet[IPv6].src
```

Now as I had commented back when this question was originally asked, for older
`scapy` versions (that don't support ipv6 parsing):

- [`pyshark`](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) can be used instead (`pyshark` is a tshark wrapper) like so:

---

```
import pyshark

shark_cap = pyshark.FileCapture('file.pcap')
for packet in shark_cap:
    print packet.ipv6.src
```

- or even of course [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) (kind of the terminal version of wireshark):

---

```
$ tshark -r file.pcap -q -Tfields -e ipv6.src
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using scapy and read the file Iteratively I'd recommend you to give it a shot to [`PcapReader()`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html)

It would do the same you tried to do with `pyshark` but in Scapy

```
from scapy.all import *

for packet in PcapReader('file.pcap')
    try:
        print(packet[IPv6].src)
    except:
        pass
```

I'd recommend wrapping this around just as a failsafe if you have any packet that does not have an IPv6 address.

Comment: I have a pcap file I run the above code with IPv6, IPv4 for both types it didn't print anything.

Comment: @umairmehmood have you checked you have any IPv6 packet? 

I've downloaded a file from https://packetlife.net/captures/protocol/ipv6/ and this is running:

In [1]: from scapy.all import *
In [2]: pcap_file = '/tmp/lispmn_IPv6-RLOC.pcapng.cap'
In [3]: for packet in PcapReader(pcap_file):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         print(packet[IPv6].src)
   ...:     except:
   ...:         pass
   ...: 
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c
2607:f2c0:f00f:b001::face:b00c